# Mongodb not equal to 0 not working with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb.

I am using aggregation query. In which i am adding `$match` pipeline for matching sub-document.

```
var aggregatePipes= [{ "$unwind": "$payload" }, { "$sort": { "payload.r": 1 } }];     
aggregatePipes.push({ '$match': { 'payload.r': { '$ne': 0 } } });
```

My document is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ....,
    "activationId" : ....,
    "parentActivationId" : ....),
    "m" : "c9:8c:2f:61:e7:f8",
    "status" : "new",
    "payload" : [ 
        {
            "r" : -67,
            "t" : ISODate("2017-12-18T11:42:43.964Z")
        }, 
        {
            "r" : 0,
            "t" : ISODate("2017-12-18T11:42:47.073Z")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-18T11:43:51.732Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-18T11:43:51.732Z"),
    "deviceId" : "DEVICEID"
}
```

If i use any number instead of 0 then it works fine. But is is not working with 0.

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?

Comment: I just tested and it works fine for me. Would you mind to provide the exact document and the expected/actual result you're getting?

Comment: I am just checking payload.r !=0 & it's returning empty array. if i use any other number it's working fine

Comment: provide the exact document. Also, check if `payload.r` is a number or string

Comment: Also check if your collection in your mongo server matches then one you use in mongoose

Comment: `aggregatePipes` is only where you build your query. Can you also provide   the part of code where you apply the query to?

Comment: Just tested this in MongoDB 3.6 and works perfectly fine with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS might be resolving `$ne: 0` as `$ne == false` in some condition in mongo. You may try resolving this by using `$ne: Number( 0 )` instead

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it still returns empty array. For any other number it is working fine. Strange behavior.